# Android синхронизация

Tags: java, android, асинхронность

Имеется приложение (планировщик задач).
Как можно организовать синхронизацию, чтобы задачи добавленные на одно устройство, отображались на другом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариантов много - нужно наверное какое то хранилище или сервер, или сервис.

Если нужен рил-тайм посмотрите в  сторону Firebase, для вас это будет выглядеть как подписка на изменения. https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/examples.html

Есть очень хороший курс на Udacity https://www.udacity.com/courses/ud009

Comment: спасибо, помогли)